# Behaviour of attempting to access a character at index -1 for std::string?

Tags: c++, string

Is there any guaranteed behaviour for attempting to access a character at `-1` in a std::string?

Eg if I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
  if (str[i-1] == 'a' && str[i+1] == 'c') {
    //etc
  }
}
```

Then on the first iteration it will do `str[-1]`, what does the standard say will happen? I know it says in C++11 that str[str.size()] will return the null character, but sites like cppreference and cplusplus don't say anything about other out of bounds accesses.

(if I run the code above, then nothing bad happens, but I want to make sure that this is standard)

Comment: _"Is there any guaranteed behaviour ..."_ No that's undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: Nasal demons everywhere.

Comment: Are you asking about out of bounds access or specifically about what happens with `-1`?

Comment: Well specifically -1, but also greater than .size()

Comment: @Jonathan. `-1` is almost guaranteed to be larger than `.size()`, which means UB.

Comment: There is no character at -1, so the question is meaningless.

Comment: @PeteBecker, no it's not meaningless as you can still type str[-1]...

Comment: Though I should have realised that the index is unsigned and so would be larger than size()

Comment: @Jonathan - there is no character at -1, so it's meaningless to ask about "the character at ... -1", which is in your title and your opening sentence.

Comment: Ok "attempting to access a character at index -1"?

Comment: While yes there is usually no character at -1. The question is not meaningless. I asked about accessing the character at 1.5 or "foo", then that would be meaningless, but -1 is a valid argument to the [] operator.

Comment: And actually as the answers here show, you can have a character at -1, given a string of the maximum length as the index is unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any guaranteed behaviour for access the character at -1 in a std::string?

Formally, it depends. In practice, it is *undefined behaviour*, so there are no guarantees.

The parameter of `operator[]` is unsigned, so `-1` is the maximum value that type can hold (`std::numeric_limits<std::string::size_type>::max()`). Since that is also the maximum value `std::string::size()` can hold, it could be well defined *only* in the (extremely improbable) case that the string has the largest size allowed, in which case a reference to the null terminator is returned.

From the C++11 standard, and the N3936 draft of the C++14 standard,

> **21.4.5 basic_string element access [string.access]**
>
> ```
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> reference       operator[](size_type pos);
> ```
>
> 1. Requires: `pos <= size()`.
> 2. Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where
>      modifying the object leads to undefined behavior. ....

Comment: It is formally defined, and no it is not undefined behavior in C++11.

Comment: I am not sure having -1 a valid index is allowed by standard. `std::string::size_type(-1)` is also a value of `std::string::npos` and it has a special meaning in many functions and appears in many pre/postconditions (usually in form `... != npos`). So it might conflict with something in this case.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot As far as operator[] goes, it is like I said here.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It is defined to be undefined behaviour if `pos` is greater than `size()`. And this will be the case in most realistic scenarios, because it is very unlikely that one can actually construct a string with the largest possible size.

Comment: @juanchopanza What about my quote from c++11 standard?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That is not the quote I have in the C++11 standard. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N 3690 Date: 2013-05-15

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It must be an error in that draft. The text in the C++11 standard (from which I quoted) and N3936 is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Quoted from c++11 standard:

> [string.access]
>
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
>   reference operator[](size_type pos);
>
> Requires: pos <= size(). Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.
>
> Throws: Nothing.
>
> Complexity: constant time
>
> Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size().

Your -1 is converted to the unsigned `size_type`, producing the maximum value of the type.

It then it should return a nul char.

Note: my clang doesn't have this behavior and says in its docs that *data access with this operator is unchecked and out_of_range lookups are not defined.*

Comment: Isn't "otherwise" referring to "if pos is greater than string length" here?

Comment: At first glance, -1 appears to be less than the string length. Add to your answer that -1 is converted to unsigned.

Comment: Which documentation are you quoting? In C++11 the requirement is `pos <= size()`. Did this change in C++14?

Comment: You seem to have incomplete draft. In mine it states _1 Requires: pos <= size()._ _2 Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior._ So it is defined only in cases where `pos <= size()` and returns CharT() only if `not (pos < size)` and preconditions are satisfied, i.e. `pos == size()`

Comment: Yes I changed it my last std statements.